# Find if a cell contents appears more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table body that looks like the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="basket_main">
        <td class="basket_item">
            <input type="text" class="basket_qty_txt" id="ctl00_ctl00_main_body_content_main_content_area_shopping_basket_ctl01_txt_qty_162" value="3" name="ctl00$ctl00$main_body_content$main_content_area$shopping_basket$ctl01$txt_qty_162">                    
        </td>
        <td class="basket_item prod_code" id="ctl00_ctl00_main_body_content_main_content_area_shopping_basket_ctl01_prod_code_col">
            CSM160
        </td>

        <td class="basket_item">
            SIL.MTG:RENAULT R19 1988 ON
        </td>

        <td class="basket_item max_qty">
            5
        </td>

        <td class="basket_item">
            <input type="button" class="basket_item_button">
            <input type="button" class="basket_item_button">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

There could be many rows in this table, what I'm trying to find out is if the `prod_code` appears in more than one row in the table using javascript or jquery.

Comment: Do you only want to know if there are duplicates or how many and where they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the table cells and collect the data.

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kEAzB/6/

```
var items = {};

$('tr td.basket_item.prod_code').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    if (items[value] == undefined) {
        items[value] = 0;
    }
    items[value] += 1;
});

for (key in items) {
    alert(key + ":" +items[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could scan all the table rows, store the `product codes` in an Associative Array (ie `productCodes` and check if the same `product code` is already defined.

```
var productCodesTds = document.getElementsByClassName("prod_code"),
    productCodes = Object.create(null),
    max,
    i;

for (i = 0, max = productCodesTds; i < max; i += 1) {
   productCode = productCodesTds[i].innerText;

   if (productCode in productCodes) {
       // the productCode is already defined in an other td
   }
   else {
      productCodes['productCode'] = null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

push all the codes to array

```
  var arr = new Array();

$('.prod_code').each(function(){

var prod_code = $(this).val();

    arr.push(prod_code);

});
```

sort the array and check if there are duplicate values

```
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); 

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 1) {
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
               alert("duplicate value"+sorted_arr[i + 1]);
        }
}
```